# One dimensional projection of complex analytic sets (Edited)

Tags: cv.complex-variables

This may be a well known question:

Let $X$ be a complex analytic (finite intersection of zero locus of analytic functions) subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Is it true that the projection of $X$ to the first coordinate is a finite set or the complement of a finite set?

Edit: By the example in answers the conjecture is not true, but can we refine it by considering also all discrete sets and their complements?

Answer (score 5):

Any closed set of zero logarithmic capacity can be the complement of a projection
of an analytic set in $C^2$ to $C$,
MR0369724
Alexander, H.
On a problem of Julia. 
Duke Math. J. 42 (1975), 327–332.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be the curve $(exp(2 \pi i z)-1)w=1$ in $\mathbb{C}^2_{z,w}$. Then $z$ cannot be an integer.